# How to check for a symbol such as &#9745; in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to change a symbol ☐ to another ☑. My code is below.

```html
<a onClick="changeValue()">
  <h1 id="flipSymbol">&#9745;</h1>
</a>

<script>
  function changeValue() {
    y = document.getElementById("flipSymbol").innerHTML;
    x1 = "&#9745;";
    x2 = "&#9744;";
    if (y == x1) {
      console.log("x1")
      document.getElementById("flipSymbol").innerHTML = x2;
    } else {
      console.log("x2")
      document.getElementById("flipSymbol").innerHTML = x1;
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Why aren't you using checkboxes?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep counter to switch checkbox state.

```js
var symbol = 1;
function changeValue() {
    y = document.getElementById("flipSymbol").innerHTML;
    x1 = "&#9745;";
    x2 = "&#9744;";
    if(symbol == 1){
      document.getElementById("flipSymbol").innerHTML = "&#9744;";
    }
    else{
      document.getElementById("flipSymbol").innerHTML = "&#9745;";
    }
    symbol = 1-symbol;
}
```

```html
<a onClick="changeValue()"><h1 id="flipSymbol">&#9745;</h1></a>
```

Comment: I also like the css solution but I do need to work in JS because I have a need for making this work for a table. Than you all for he excellent comments.

Comment: You can add JavaScript to it as well, difference is there's less JavaScript because UI is already taken care of so the only thing you'd need JS for is functionality.

Answer (score 1):

**Pure [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript):**

You can use directly:

```
x1 = "☑";
x2 = "☐";
```

Something like this:

```html
<a onclick="changeValue()">
  <h1 id="flipSymbol">&#9745;</h1>
</a>

<script>
  function changeValue() {
    var y = document.getElementById("flipSymbol").innerHTML,
      x1 = "☑",
      x2 = "☐";
    if (y == x1) {
      document.getElementById("flipSymbol").innerHTML = x2;
    } else {
      document.getElementById("flipSymbol").innerHTML = x1;
    }
  }
</script>
```

The same way with emojis:

```html
<a onclick="changeValue()">
  <h1 id="flipSymbol"></h1>
</a>

<script>
  function changeValue() {
    var y = document.getElementById("flipSymbol").innerHTML,
      x1 = "",
      x2 = "";
    if (y == x1) {
      document.getElementById("flipSymbol").innerHTML = x2;
    } else {
      document.getElementById("flipSymbol").innerHTML = x1;
    }
  }
</script>
```

Why?

[UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16).

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code:

```html
<a onClick="changeValue()"><h1 id="flipSymbol">&#9745;</h1></a>

<script>
   function changeValue() {
 var y = document.getElementById("flipSymbol");
 y.innerHTML = ((y.innerHTML == String.fromCharCode(9744)) ? "&#9745;" : "&#9744;");
}
</script>
```

**OR**

```html
<a onClick="changeValue()"><h1 id="flipSymbol">&#9745;</h1></a>

<script>
var count = 0;

function changeValue() {
   document.getElementById("flipSymbol").innerHTML = (count ? "&#9745;" : "&#9744;");
   count = 1-count;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.charCodeAt()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_charCodeAt.asp) and [`String.fromCharCode()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_fromCharCode.asp) functions

```
function changeValue() {
    //get Unicode of #flipSymbol value
    y = document.getElementById("flipSymbol").innerHTML.charCodeAt(0);
    // Unicode for box with check and empty box
    x1 = 9745; 
    x2 = 9744; 

    // Set #flipSymbol value with converted characters from Unicode
    if (y == x1) {
        console.log("x1")               
        document.getElementById("flipSymbol").innerHTML = String.fromCharCode(x2);
    } else {
        console.log("x2")
        document.getElementById("flipSymbol").innerHTML = String.fromCharCode(x1);
    }
}
```